# How Does Big O Scale?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, scalability

**Main Question:**

Say I have some algorithm, that runs in O(n^2).

I get that, if I input an n twice the size of the original n I get 4 doubling of the maximal time complexity.

But how does it relate to running the algorithm twice with an input size of n?

**Why I am asking:**

The reason for why I'm asking, is because I made an algorithm whose big O notation was O(log_2(n)). But running it and comparing it to O(log_2(n)) showed, that it performed FAR better for inputs at the magnitude of 1 billion. The algorithm would only be used on inputs the size of 10k-20k. Meaning that it performed wastly better than $C_1*log_2(n)$

I get that big O notation is the maximum, but it felt like I asked "How tall are you?" and the big O notation answered "I am shorter than 40 meters".

I googled around a bit and found, that big O is - "in industry" - primarily used for scalability. I.e you expect your n to reach that point where it will get close to its big O.

Then, in my case, does it even make sense to use big O notation? How does running the same algorithm multiple times, rather than increasing the input size, relate to big O notation?

Comment: They don't relate. For example, sorting half of an array twice is not the same as sorting the full array.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Hmm... Makes sense. But is there then anymore I can gather from the algorithm being O(log(n)) other than, it will be faster than that in the long run? Or would it be "useless" for me to use in practice, with input sizes of my dimension?

Comment: You describe an algorithm that runs in O(log n) time, but your question seems to be something about performance at low n and at n around 1 billion. Perhaps you're saying that the big O runtime does not accurately model the actual wall-time performance of your algorithm for small n, but your main question seems to be unrelated to that, and is maybe something about variability in runtime for fixed n. I'm left confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there then anymore I can gather from the algorithm being O(log(n)) other than, it will be faster than that in the long run?

Time required by an implementation of an O(log n) algorithm will grow very, very slowly with problem size. It will not become faster with larger problem sizes, but the growth will be minimal.

> Or would it be "useless" for me to use in practice, with input sizes of my dimension?

It depends on the available **alternatives**. If there is a faster but "worse" (big-O-wise) algorithm, it can make sense determine the input sizes where implementations of each are faster. An O(log n) will, however, always win over, say, O(n) algorithms in the long run (for big enough n). If there is no faster alternative, why worry? O(log n) is good to have, even if you do not "need" it.

Big-O only helps you to choose algorithms that can **scale as expected** as problem sizes grow. An algorithm's big-O class says *nothing* about how well a **specific implementation** of that algorithm will perform for a **specific input** on a **specific machine**. Indeed, it is frequent to use "bad" algorithms (with, say, O(n^2) complexity) instead of "good" algorithms (say, O(n log n)) for smaller problems, simply because they will be faster for those input sizes. Look at sorting: many implementations of quicksort fall back to insertsort for very small inputs:

[This line](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/be44bff34df4/src/share/classes/java/util/Arrays.java#l1327) in java's standard library source-code comes to mind: its authors have experimentally determined that, for arrays of less than 7 elements, insert-sort is quicker than quicksort.

Answer (score 3):

The bad news is that the asymptotic complexity formulas don't help predict the running-time of algorithms for practical N (I would even dare say do not help *at all*).

Because for small N, the running time is usually dominated by the low-order terms of the complexity.

And for larger N, the RAM model (constant-time access to any address) is irrelevant. The access time can vary by several orders of magnitude due to cache and virtual memory effects !

Also note that big-O analysis relates to the worst-case complexity, which can be very far from the cases you try. Even expected-case complexity may be irrelevant, because it relies on a specific input distribution, which can be unrealistic, and dispersion can be large.

Comment: That is an important note: that big-O is a simplification that is based on unlimited storage, and, say, sorting data on a real computer with limited RAM will show a huge slowdown when the input exceeds the RAM size. +1 for noting this.

Comment: I would take issue with "do not help at all". There aren't many Fuerer's algorithms out there. If you pulled two sorting algorithms out of a hat, and one of them was O(nlogn) and the other one was O(n^2), which one would you bet on?

Comment: @Sneftel: depends on n and other details.

Comment: n=1 million, no other details given (other than that neither algorithm is *absolutely stupid*.

Comment: @Sneftel: I would use QuickSort, notoriously O(N²) :-)

Comment: I like this answer, but more often than I think people assume, the RAM model is irrelevant because runtime complexity often does not measure "basic operations" even if that's what's often taught. For example, complexity discussions of sorting algorithms and hashtables use "number of comparisons" as the measure. This gives an idea of performance that is quite far from the reality of a computer.

Comment: @PaulHankin: I recall an image processing paper that was claiming constant-time per pixel performance for a filter (hence independent of the filter size). But they were relying on histogram processing, potentially requiring 65536 operations per pixel in case of a 16 bits image...